# Dynamics CRM v9.0 getIsDirty not giving refreshed value

Tags: dynamics-365

I am using dynamics CRM version

> 9.1.0.4435 online

. I am facing issues while using `formContext.data.entity.getIsDirty()` in Save event.

In CRM version below then **9.0**, `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty()` gave us value based on one latest status of fields and if I call this method in every minute it was working well.

But as in v9.0 it replaced by `formContext.data.entity.getIsDirty()`, it is not giving me value equal to TRUE even there is dirty field present. Does anyone knows workaround or knows any cause for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to replicate your issue on my Instance for OnSave Event.

My CRM Version: Version 1710 (9.1.0.4435) online

What I tried and worked for me.

```
function testFunction(executionContext){

    var formcontext = executionContext.getFormContext(); // gives me formcontext

    formcontext.data.getIsDirty() // returns True for me when form is dirty

    formcontext.getAttribute("caseorigincode").getIsDirty() // return true when this field is changes

    formcontext.getAttribute("emailaddress").getIsDirty() // returns false as this field was not changed.

    formcontext.data.entity.getIsDirty() // even this function returns true as form is dirty
}
```

Comment: Hello AnkUser, Thank you so much for doing this. Here, you need to user timeout javascript method to delay the operation for second and you can see getIsDirty will be false even if the save operation is in running mode.